# Is language of android application depended on phone model / company?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm writing an android application and I've translated it on English and Greek. Everything works fine in almost every device. The problem is a `Samsung galaxy s4` and a `Samsung icore2`.

Both of these phones don't seem to like the Greek language. I changed it programmatically, nothing. I tried to change the whole system language, still nothing.

To change the language programmatically I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/3671272) and it works everywhere everytime (except those two samsung devices). Even if it didn't work, the application should've had the system language like every other device.

So the question is: Is language change something that varies in different devices? Or is it a known samsung issue?

**Edit 1:**

I want to provide some more information.

One of the users of my application reported it to me. He said that even though he selected Greek language, the application continued to be in English.

Then, I asked him to change the system language to Greek and re-install the application. Still nothing. The system language was Greek but the application appeared in English.

Comment: "it works everywhere everytime" - then what is the problem?

Comment: "Both of these phones don't seem to like the Greek language" -- it would help if you would provide a clear technical description of your symptoms.

Comment: @cricket_007 obviously except those two phones. That's what the question is about. But you're right it is misleading. I edited my post.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't have unfortunately. One of my users reported it to me. If they give me more information of course I will update the post. I edited the post though, trying to be more thorough.